# How can I store the file that find produces i.e the actual file and contents as a file and not the console output of find?

Tags: linux, bash, file, scripting, find

Currently I'm doing this to try and store the actual file and its contents the `find` command finds as I'm searching for a file named `Myfile`:

```
find /Users/Documents -name Myfile > outputfile
```

The contents of `Myfile` is:

```
This is my original file.
```

however when I go to perform an operation, such as `cat outputfile` it takes the actual output of the `find` command,rather than the file itself and displays:

```
/Users/Documents/Myfile
```

I am expecting when I do `cat outputfile`:

```
This is my original file.
```

How can I store the file itself and perform operations on it? My particular use case is to perform static analysis of the file and I need to pass it as an argument. I have recently found using `find`. I don't care for displaying the output of the command. I want to find a file based on the name of the file, then perform a scan and work with the contents of that original file, by storing it as a variable. The reason I want to store it as a variable is so that I can pass it as an argument to another program.

Comment: Why do you expect that? `find -exec cat {} +` would do what you want; but `find` alone simply lists the names of matching files.

Comment: Your question is still not clear after your edit. I suggest to add an example and show what files are present and what command(s) you want to run with the file(s) found by `find`. Note that `find` may find more than one matching file, e.g. if you have `/Users/Documents/Myfile` and `/Users/Documents/somedirectory/Myfile`. Define what should happen in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store the path to the file in a variable, use:

```
fil=$(find /Users/Documents -name Myfile)
```

To actually redirect the output of the found file(s) use the exec flag in find and so:

```
find /Users/Documents -name Myfile -exec cat '{}' \; > outputfile
```

If you want to store the output in a variable as opposed to redirect to a file you can use:

```
conts=$(find /Users/Documents -name Myfile -exec cat '{}' \;)
```

Comment: If you just want the path stored in a variable, use fil=$(find /Users/Documents -name Myfile)

Comment: @i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i Storing the file name or file contents in a variable might result in problems. Depending on what exactly you want to do with the file(s) found, it might be better to run the command directly from find, e.g. `find /Users/Documents -name Myfile -exec yourcommand '{}' \;`

Comment: As can be seen from the question, I want to use the file as an argument to run a static analysis tool, which requires a certain file as an argument -> "My particular use case is to perform static analysis of the file and I need to pass it as an argument." - it's not possible to execute in the way you have demonstrated due to this. Raman Sailopal answer is sufficient.

Comment: If the solution meets your requirements, please take the time to accept the solution as an answer.

Comment: Agree with @Bodo this is what `exec` is for.

Comment: @i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i'i Does your statement "it's not possible to execute in the way you have demonstrated due to this" refer to my comment with `find ... -exec ...`? This will pass the file name as an argument to `yourcommand`. If you would make clear in your question what exactly you want to do with the file it would be easier to provide a good solution. The purpose of this site is not only to answer a question for you personally, but to provide a reference of questions and answers for people that may have a similar problem. That's why the question should clearly state your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Other  options  you could  use are  the  following:

```
find /Users/Documents -name Myfile | xargs cat > outputfile


find /Users/Documents -name Myfile -print0 | xargs -0 cat > outputfile
```

-print0 enables printing of the full file path on the standard output, followed by a null character and -0 xargs flag effectively deals with space in filenames.

Best Regards